# How to update repository / google play services?

Tags: android, sdk

How i must update repository / google play services? My last version is 7.3.0

There is no update in SDK manager or installing missing component

[image]

What's wrong?

---

**Solved problem
In tools > option > set a proxy server and port**

Comment: Did you try by clicking on "Select Updates" ?

Comment: And nothing was selected ?

Comment: put the mouse over the gradle compile line. It will tell you which version is the most up to date. Change that number and that's it. (if message complains, it'll give you a link to update that library)

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla Can you say where is gradle compile line ?

Comment: @Cyprien Aubry No nothing for update

Comment: @saadat68 this is an example. Over the build.gradle inside app you'll have a thing like: compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.0.0' and I want the 23.0.1 version... then, change it to: compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0' and sync the gradle file

Comment: I test it and doesn't work. you can see in screenshot. ( installing missing component)

Comment: Is there anyway to update it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open SDK Manager->Tools->Manage Add-on Sites then click on "Enable All" so that you get updates from the sources.
2. If the above solution doesn't work then click on Tools->Options. Check the "Force HTTP instead of HTTPS..." option and try again.

Let me know if doesn't work. We can try to debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks but there is nothing in Manage Add-on to enable and second way doesn't work too

Comment: @saadat68 Launch SDK Manager from it's location, I mean start the exe process and don't start it from Android Studio